# What are the impacts of changing authentication on SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sharepoint

We are using SQL Server 2008 and the only thing that is using it is SharePoint at the moment. Accounting had purchased Sage Fixed Assets which requires Mixed Mode authentication on SQL Server and we are currently using Windows Authentication. I know very little about the internals of SQL Server and SharePoint. What if any impact would there be on SharePoint if I changed authentication?

Thanks,
Norm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing: "Mixed" includes "Windows Authentication".

Sharepoint uses "Windows Authentication" so will be unaffected.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I was hoping that was the answer.

Comment: Also, this does not seems to be the OPs case but it is important to put on record, is that if one wants to create an application that runs under SharePoint and uses SQL, or a WebPart that connects to a Database you can only achieve that with Mixed auth, since sharepoint uses impersonation you will get all sorts of crazy SQL authentication attemps, including NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON. TL;DR Windows Auth won't work on secondary SQL connections under a SharePoint Web Application.

Comment: @F.Aquino: if you enable Kerberos pass through, you can get it to work. http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/06/13/understanding-kerberos-double-hop.aspx Just like for linked servers Or http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/how-to-perform-the-dreaded-double-hop-with-linked-servers/3301#3301